# WebGL draw loop and translation

Tags: javascript, webgl

I'm want my javascript program to be shifting a triangle to the right. 
What I'm focusing on right now are matrices and draw loops. I've never done such a thing so I may be off road but what I'm attempting to do, for study purposes is this:

-Setup the webgl pipeline so I display correctly a triangle (OK)

-Write a function with a matrix that allows me to pass in the values of translation (seems ok but I'm not sure)

```
var translation_prototype = [1,0,0,0,
                             0,1,0,0,
                             0,0,1,0,
                             tx,ty,0,1];
```

Leaving out for the moment rotation a scaling and modelview, since I'm perfectly happy(just for the sake of an exercise) with the orthographic view webgl provides.

-Setup a loop that cycles through the drawArrays (even here I'm not sure if the loop starts and ends in the correct place)

I suspect I'm really close, but the triangle doesn't move (tx remains constant).

Here's the code(I think I don't even need to clear the color and depth buffer since I'm only translating on x axis)

```html
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
        <canvas id = "can" width="400" height="400">
        </canvas>
    
        <script>
            var webgl_canvas = document.getElementById('can');
            var gl = webgl_canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
            var triangles = [-0.8,-0.8,0,0.8,-0.8,0,0,0.8,0];
            var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
            var tx = 0.1;
            var ty = 0;
            var translation_prototype = [1,0,0,0,
                                         0,1,0,0,
                                         0,0,1,0,
                                         tx,ty,0,1]; 
            
            var vertexShader_source = 'attribute vec3 a_position;' + 'uniform vec4 u_translation;' + 'void main() { gl_Position = u_translation * vec4 (a_position,1);}';
            var fragmentShader_source = 'precision mediump float;' + 'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.9,0,0.1,1); }';

            function getTimeInSeconds () {
                return Date.now() * 0.001;
            }
            
            function makeTranslation (tx, ty) {
                return translation_prototype;  
            }
            
            //Compile shaders
            var buildShader = function (shaderSource, typeOfShader) {
                var shader = gl.createShader(typeOfShader);
                gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
                gl.compileShader(shader);
                if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                    alert (gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
                }
                return shader;
            }
            
            var compiledVertexShader = buildShader (vertexShader_source, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            var compiledFragmentShader = buildShader (fragmentShader_source, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            
            //setup GLSL program
            program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(program,compiledVertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(program,compiledFragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(program);
            
            //Fill the buffer with vertex data
            
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(triangles), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 
            vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
            vertexBuffer.numItems = 3;

            gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
            gl.useProgram(program);
            var shaderTranlsationMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderTranlsationMatrix,false,new Float32Array(translation_prototype));
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        
            var startTime = 0;
            function animate (time) {
                //Draw loop
                gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                var deltaTime = (time - startTime);
                makeTranslation((tx*deltaTime),(ty*deltaTime));
                console.log(tx,ty,deltaTime);
        
                gl.drawArrays (gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numItems);
                startTime = time;
    
                window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            }
    
            animate(0);
        </script>
    </html>
```

```
<!-- start last edited snippet -->


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<canvas id = "can" width="400" height="400">

</canvas>


<script>
var webgl_canvas = document.getElementById('can');
var gl = webgl_canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');

var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array([-1,-1,0,1,-1,0,0,1,0]), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 

vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
vertexBuffer.numItems = 3;

var identityMatrix = [1,0,0,0,
                      0,1,0,0,
                      0,0,1,0,
                      0,0,0,1];

function translation (tx,ty,tz) {
    return [1,0,0,0,
            0,1,0,0,
            0,0,1,0,
           tx,ty,tz,1]
}


var vertexShader_source = 'attribute vec3 a_position;' + 'uniform mat4 u_move;' + 'void main() { gl_Position = u_move * vec4 (a_position,1); }';
var fragmentShader_source = 'precision mediump float;' + 'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.9,0,0.1,1); }';







//Compile shaders
var buildShader = function (shaderSource, typeOfShader) {
var shader = gl.createShader(typeOfShader);
gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
gl.compileShader(shader);
if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
    alert (gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
}
return shader;
}

var compiledVertexShader = buildShader (vertexShader_source, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
var compiledFragmentShader = buildShader (fragmentShader_source, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);

//setup GLSL program
program = gl.createProgram();
gl.attachShader(program,compiledVertexShader);
gl.attachShader(program,compiledFragmentShader);
gl.linkProgram(program);



var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
gl.useProgram(program);


var tx = 0, ty = 0, tz = 0;
var translate = gl.getUniformLocation (program, "u_move");
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(translate,false,new Float32Array(identityMatrix));
gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

//Draw
var start_time =0;
var animate=function(time) {
var dt= time-start_time;
tx+=0.5;
translation((dt*tx),0,0);
console.log(dt);
console.log(tx);
start_time=time;
gl.drawArrays (gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numItems);
window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
animate(0);
</script>

</html>

<!-- end last edited snippet -->
```

Comment: If you `console.log` the translation_prototype variable in the loop function you will see that is not changing! So your triangle doesn't move

Comment: Yes Boyd I know that. I can't understand why.

Comment: also your vertex shader is wrong. You have to multiply you translation uniform with the position vector to get the final moving result

Comment: Ops, sorry, forgot that. I've put the multiplication in the EDIT. But now the triangle disappeared.

Comment: Oh and also your uniform should be a mat4 as you pass it with the uniformMatrix4fv() function, not a vec4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the working snippet

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/w9m5qc9a/)**

**Your vertex shader should look like this:**

```
attribute vec3 a_position;' + 'uniform mat4 u_translation;' + 'void main() { gl_Position = u_translation*vec4 (a_position,1);}
```

- In order to make objects move in space you have to multiply all your vectors and matrices with the position vector to get the result. [Tranlation Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(geometry))

**You have to update your `translation_prototype` variable every loop cycle:**

```
    deltaTime += 0.005;
    makeTranslation(tx+deltaTime,ty+deltaTime);
```

- the `deltaTime` was declared outside the loop and incremented every cycle

**Also your `makeTranslation` function should look like this:**

```
function makeTranslation (x, y) {
    translation_prototype = 
            [1,0,0,0,
             0,1,0,0,
             0,0,1,0,
             x,y,0,1]
    return translation_prototype;  
}
```

- (you can get rid of the return statement if you are using global variables, though is recommended to use local variables)

*(I had to try this new snippet feature :D)*

```js
 var webgl_canvas = document.getElementById('can');
    var gl = webgl_canvas.getContext('experimental-webgl');
    var triangles = [-0.5,-0.5,0,0.5,-0.5,0,0,0.5,0];
    var vertexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
    var tx = 0;
    var ty = 0;
    var translation_prototype = [1,0,0,0,
                 -               0,1,0,0,
                                 0,0,1,0,
                                 0,0,0,1]; 
    
    var vertexShader_source = 'attribute vec3 a_position;' + 'uniform mat4 u_translation;' + 'void main() { gl_Position = u_translation*vec4 (a_position,1);}';
    var fragmentShader_source = 'precision mediump float;' + 'void main() { gl_FragColor = vec4 (0.9,0,0.1,1); }';
    
    
    
    function getTimeInSeconds () {
     return Date.now() * 0.001;
    }
    
    function makeTranslation (x, y) {
        translation_prototype = 
                [1,0,0,0,
                 0,1,0,0,
                 0,0,1,0,
                 x,y,0,1]
     return translation_prototype;  
    }
    
    
    //Compile shaders
    var buildShader = function (shaderSource, typeOfShader) {
    var shader = gl.createShader(typeOfShader);
    gl.shaderSource(shader, shaderSource);
    gl.compileShader(shader);
    if (!gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
     alert (gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
    }
    return shader;
    }
    
    var compiledVertexShader = buildShader (vertexShader_source, gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
    var compiledFragmentShader = buildShader (fragmentShader_source, gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    
    //setup GLSL program
    program = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(program,compiledVertexShader);
    gl.attachShader(program,compiledFragmentShader);
    gl.linkProgram(program);
    
    //Fill the buffer with vertex data
    
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(triangles), gl.STATIC_DRAW); 
    vertexBuffer.itemSize = 3;
    vertexBuffer.numItems = 3;
    
    
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program,"a_position");
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    gl.useProgram(program);
    var shaderTranlsationMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
    gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderTranlsationMatrix,false,new Float32Array(translation_prototype));
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     
    var startTime = 0;
    var deltaTime = 0;
    function animate (time) {
    
     //Draw loop
        gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     deltaTime += 0.005;
        makeTranslation(tx+deltaTime,ty+deltaTime);
        
        gl.useProgram(program);
        var shaderTranlsationMatrix = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "u_translation");
        gl.uniformMatrix4fv(shaderTranlsationMatrix,false,new Float32Array(translation_prototype));
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, vertexBuffer.itemSize, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
     
     gl.drawArrays (gl.TRIANGLES, 0, vertexBuffer.numItems);
     startTime = time;
    
     window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
    
    animate(0);
```

```html
<canvas id = "can" width="300" height="300">

</canvas>
```

Comment: Isn't the draw loop suppose to change the movement variables and not the time? It looks as this code would run slower on slow machines. Though the output is ok, I'm thinking about a slider or something to control the movement of the mesh. Now it's completely time independent. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can use the time too.Just replace the += 0.005 with your function `getTimeInSeconds()` ( http://jsfiddle.net/w9m5qc9a/1/ )

Comment: Ok, I'm almost there. I need more than a working code, just to wrap my head around some concepts. So, basically, thanks to your inputs I've understood that: 1) I need and identity matrix, just to fill the gl.matrixuniform, then I can call the translation matrix and do the multiply. 2) I need to pass to the matrix some values, which are going to be changing in the draw loop(looking at the console it is correctly drawing every 16 milliseconds, more or less). Now even the translation x parameter is increment but the triangle is still not moving. I attach the code in the EDIT.

Comment: Here it is moving ( http://jsfiddle.net/tzvdLsxn/ ) .Your problem: you didn't updated the u_move matrix in the vertex shader with the returned value from your `translation` function.